# Динамические модули в vue

Tags: vue.js, архитектура, ecmascript-6

Есть некий сайт на vue, на котором будут различные инструменты (Например Калькулятор, Гугл карта и Рисовалка). Я создаю папку modules, в ней 3 vue файла: calc.vue, map.vue, paint.vue. В шапке сайта есть меню, куда я могу успешно подгрузить ссылки и вывести выбраный компонент в route-view, это не проблема. Но хотелось бы как-то автоматизировать этот процесс таким образом, чтобы при добавлении в папку нового модуля (или удалении старого), мне не пришлось бы руками править все маршруты, т.е. чтобы меню и роуты строилось автоматический (Причем на некоторых инструментах могут быть и дочерние маршруту).

Мне пришла идея: в каждом модуле создать переменную типа route: {path: '/paint', name: 'paint', component: this}, а в route.js (Vue Router, файл с маршрутами) нужно получить все vue файлы из папки modules, а затем сформировать файл маршрутов. Далее каким-нибудь образом получить все маршруты и вывести их в меню. Как считаете, хорошая ли это идея или есть варианты получше? И могли бы привести примеры кода, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: На счет Вашей идеи, риторический вопрос: чем она отличается от стандартного добавления путей в файле  route?

Comment: Посмотрите на Nuxt. Там роутинг вроде бы так и строится.

Comment: Но, я думаю, что динамически строя route.js, Вы лишите себя половины его возможностей, например: алиасы, динамические пути..

Comment: @Дмытрык, мне кажется это может добавить немного гибкости. Можно поставить какой-нибудь флаг в компоненте, например isDisable, и "построитель" маршрутов автоматический не будет включать этот компонент, таким образом мы не лезем руками в маршруты, а лишь работаем с компонентами, включаем, отключаем, а маршруты строятся сами. Хотя может я и ошибаюсь в своем подходе.